# Solr Join not returing any results

Tags: solr, inner-join

I am using Solr 8.10 as docker with custom schema that contains the following lines:

```
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="relationship_name" type="keywordAnalyzer" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="entity_docRef1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="entity_docRef2" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="created_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="modified_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="created_by" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="modified_by" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />


    <dynamicField name="___target*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="___source*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="___link*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

I have created the following data using postman

```
[
  {
    "id": "44",
    "relationship_name": "Co-insured",
    "entity_docRef1": "HomeInsurence/1",
    "entity_docRef2": "BusinessPartner/Tomas",
    "created_at": "2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
    "created_by": "admin",
    "modified_at": "2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
    "modified_by": "admin",
    "fulltext": "data",
    "___target.name": "Tomas Bajus",
    "___target.region": "Slovakia",
    "___source.contract.company": "Generali",
    "___source.contract.id": "Generali/1",
    "___link.signed_at": "2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "48",
    "relationship_name": "PostalAddress",
    "entity_docRef1": "BusinessPartner/Tomas",
    "entity_docRef2": "PostalAddress/1",
    "created_at": "2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
    "created_by": "admin",
    "modified_at": "2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
    "modified_by": "admin",
    "fulltext": "data",
    "___source.name": "Tomas Bajus",
    "___source.region": "Slovakia",
    "___target.City": "Presov",
    "___target.Street_name": "Hlavna 1",
    "___target.zip": "08271"
  }
]
```

The created data are visible in the Solr using admin console:

```
 {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fl":"*",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "_":"1634718235445"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"44",
        "relationship_name":"Co-insured",
        "entity_docRef1":"HomeInsurence/1",
        "entity_docRef2":"BusinessPartner/Tomas",
        "created_at":"2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
        "created_by":"admin",
        "modified_at":"2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
        "modified_by":"admin",
        "___target.name":"Tomas Bajus",
        "___target.region":"Slovakia",
        "___source.contract.company":"Generali",
        "___source.contract.id":"Generali/1",
        "___link.signed_at":"2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
        "_version_":1714126727193559040},
      {
        "id":"48",
        "relationship_name":"PostalAddress",
        "entity_docRef1":"BusinessPartner/Tomas",
        "entity_docRef2":"PostalAddress/1",
        "created_at":"2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
        "created_by":"admin",
        "modified_at":"2021-10-18T14:38:20.985Z",
        "modified_by":"admin",
        "___source.name":"Tomas Bajus",
        "___source.region":"Slovakia",
        "___target.City":"Presov",
        "___target.Street_name":"Hlavna 1",
        "___target.zip":"08271",
        "_version_":1714126727567900672}]
  }}
```

I am trying to execute the following join

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"{!join from=entity_docRef1 to=entity_docRef2}___target.zip: 08271",
      "fl":"*",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "_":"1634718235445"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }}
```

but I have no responses. My intention is to get the document 44 in the result set by filtering on `___target.zip` on other document.

What am I doing wrong? Why there is no result from the join query? I thought that the id must be specified in the join `to` to statement but there is no such a requirement specified in the documentation of Solr https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/other-parsers.html#join-query-parser

> from
> The name of a field which contains values to look for in the "to" field. Can be single or multi-valued, but must have a field type compatible with the field represented in the "to" field. This parameter is required.

> to
> The name of a field whose value(s) will be checked against those found in the "from" field. Can be single or multi-valued, but must have a field type compatible with the "from" field. This parameter is required.

I have tried the join statements from the examples and this one works fine but the join request look exactly the same

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by updating the `solrconfig.xml` by adding `JoinParser`